# Thymeleaf: pass input text as parameter in href

Tags: javascript, html, spring, templates, thymeleaf

I have a `input` field, whose value is set by the controller by `response.query`, within the template I also have two links which perform `read` and `delete` calls to the `id` entered in the `query`. Here is the template.

```
<div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" th:value="*{response.query}" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <li><a href="#" th:href="@{/read/{id}(id=response.query)}">Read</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" th:href="@{/delete/{id}(id=response.query)">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the `href` parameter always gets passed as `null`. Is there alternate approach to this?

Comment: this was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Well let me see if I understand what you want :

For example you put '5' in the text input. Now you want to href to:

`http://localhost:8080/read/5`

And you have a controller which looks something like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/read/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String read(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
  // your logic goes here
  return "read"; 
}
```

Firstly my suggestion is that you can just change your code from :

```
<li><a href="#" th:href="@{/read/{id}(id=response.query)}">Read</a></li>
```

to:

```
<li><a href="#" th:href="@{/read/{id}(id=${response.query})}">Read</a></li>
```

Comment: Yes that is correct I have a controller that looks similar to that, all I want is a input text field binded to a field and two href one to read and one to delete with the field value as parameter in both case.

Comment: So did it worked : replacing the following `th:href="@{/read/{id}(id=response.query)}` with the `th:href="@{/read/{id}(id=${response.query})}"`

Comment: this is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can't get `response.query` because it's on client side then you call it. In your case you need the javascript, which will be construct your link's URL (othervise you need a form to submit value of the input) :

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="myval" th:value="*{response.query}" />
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a href="#" onclick="onReadClick();" href="#">Read</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" th:href="@{/delete/{id}(id=response.query)">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>   

<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
function onReadClick() {
    var id = $('#myval').value; 
    /*[+
    var myUrl = [[@{/read}]] + id; 
    +]*/
    window.location.href = myUrl;
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```